# When clicking on button there need is a rain of images for 10 sec

Tags: loops, button, time, onclick

So, i have a button, when i click on that button there needs to be a rain of images for 10 seconds from the left corner to the right corner. I don't have any idea how to start with this since i am new with js. I got a button with a onclick element. Someone can help?

```
<button id="rain" type="button">Let it rain!</button>
```

*UPD from comments:*

So i got a button , when i click on that button there needs to be a rain of Nyan Cats for 10secs. So i probaly need to use a loop with the same images it and these cats needs to move from the left corner of my screen to the right corner to my screen. this needs to be 10secs and then it stops

Comment: Hello, Merel and welcome on stackoverflow!
Please, try to edit your question: add more details and add the code which you've already tried. Thank you.
P.S.
Probably you should take a look on CSS animations.

Comment: i need to do it with js it says . So yeah. I shall try to explain it better. So i got a button , when i click on that button there needs to be a rain of Nyan Cats for 10secs. So i probaly need to use a loop with the same images it and these cats needs to move from the left corner of my screen to the right corner to my screen. this needs to be 10secs and then it stops

Comment: HTML code: <body class="swapimg" background="Achtergrond.jpeg">
  <button id="rain" type="button" value="Toggle Background">Let it rain!</button>
</body>

Comment: thats everything i got now